# Using 1-Layer Fully-Connected Neural Network to Appoximate Exponential Functions

Tags: neural-networks, approximation

Consider a 1-layer fully-connected neural network (FCNN) given by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\sigma\!\left({w_i}^T x\right)
$$
where $x,w_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $v_i\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\sigma(y)=\max(y,0)$ is the ReLU activation function.

According to my professor, he was telling us that it is not possible for this $f(x)$ to approximate an exponential function $g(x)=e^x$ but I don't understand why though. Can someone please explain to me why is this the case and what are the ways to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A *single* ReLU unit is an *approximation* to $g(x)$ (whether or not you think it's a *good* approximation is a matter of taste, but we can make this more specific). More concretely, if we specify some tolerance $\epsilon$, and some interval $[a,b]$, then we can define a sense in which a single ReLU is a "good enough" approximation, by which I mean $| f(x) - g(x) | < \epsilon ~\forall x \in [a,b]$.

Naturally, outside of the interval $[a,b]$, the approximation can be arbitrarily bad. This is probably what your professor meant -- that NNs are only good at approximating functions in a specific interval.

This is the basic outline of the so-called "[universal approximation theorems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=universal%20approximation%20answers%3A1%20score%3A3)", of which Cybenko's theorem is the most famous. (But Cybenko considered sigmoid activation functions, not ReLU.)

Without more context, it's impossible to know what your professor meant, exactly, but there is definitely a specific sense in which you can *approximate* $g(x)$ using a single layer of ReLU units.

Answer (score 1):

I think your professor means that $e^x$ cannot be approximated by a single layer of ReLU globally (on the entire $\mathbb{R}$), which seems correct because whatever the output of a single layer of ReLU is, it grows linearly, not exponentially.

Meaning that the output of your network cannot be equal to a function that grows exponentially, such as $e^x$.